# How do I pass objects in EventArgs

Tags: c#, eventargs

I have a usercontrol that raises an event after communicating with a web service. The parent handles this event when raised. What I *thought* would be the proper approach would be to pass the object returned from the webservice to the parent as eventargs???

If this is the proper way I can't seem to find the instructions on how to do so.

> UserControl

```
public event EventHandler LoginCompleted;
```

then later after the service returns biz object:

```
if (this.LoginCompleted != null)
{
    // This is where I would attach / pass my biz object no?
    this.LoginCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

> Parent

```
ctrl_Login.LoginCompleted += ctrl_Login_LoginCompleted;
....snip....
void ctrl_Login_LoginCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get my object returned by login
}
```

So my question is what would be the "approved" method for getting the user object back to the parent? Create a property class that everything can access and put it there?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You would have to declare your event using `EventHandler<T>` where `T` is your class that derives from `EventArgs`:

```
public event EventHandler<LoginCompletedEventArgs> LoginCompleted;
```

`LoginCompletedEventArgs` could look like this:

```
public class LoginCompletedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly YourBusinessObject _businessObject;

    public LoginCompletedEventArgs(YourBusinessObject businessObject)
    {
        _businessObject = businessObject;
    }

    public YourBusinessObject BusinessObject
    {
        get { return _businessObject; }
    }
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
private void RaiseLoginCompleted(YourBusinessObject  businessObject)
{
    var handler = LoginCompleted;
    if(handler == null)
        return;

    handler(this, new LoginCompletedEventArgs(businessObject));
}
```

Please notice how I implemented `RaiseLoginCompleted`. This is a thread-safe version of raising the event. I eliminates a possible `NullReferenceException` that can occur in a race condition scenario where one thread wants to raise the event and another thread un-subscribes the last handler after the `if` check but before actually invoking the handler.

Answer (score 14):

Well, you could do all that or you could define a delegate as your EventHandler and define your properties in its signature.

Such as:

```cs
public delegate void MyEventEventHandler(int prop1, string prop2, object prop3...);

public event MyEventEventHandler MyEvent;
```

Answer (score 7):

I recommend use [named tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) with `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`.

I like olddog's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52651996/4100915). Microsoft already has this delegate [EventHandler< TEventArgs >](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.EventHandler%601)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-2.0).

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

You don't need to inherits from `EventArgs`.

Declare your event handler with named tuples.

```
public event EventHandler<(int id, string message, object LoginObject)> LoginCompleted;
```

In your client code, assign method to the LoginCompleted event handler

option 1: use lambda

```
LoginCompleted  += (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, sender is {o.ToString()}! id is {e.id}, message is {e.message}, and LoginObject is {e.LoginObject.ToString()}. ");
};
```

option 2: call a local method

```
LoginCompleted  += onLoginCompleted;

private static void onLoginCompleted  (object sender, (int id, string message,  object LoginObject) e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, sender is {sender.ToString()}! id is {e.id}, message is {e.message}, and LoginObject is {e.LoginObject.ToString()}. ");
}
```

I just wrote an example, please refer to my [repo](https://github.com/jk9112605/EvntArgsWithTuple/tree/master)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The repo was a big help. This is the simplest and easiest solution

Answer (score 5):

I personally like Toni Petrina's approach (see https://coderwall.com/p/wkzizq/generic-eventargs-class). It differs from the accepted answer in that you don't have to create a special EventHandler class (e.g. `LoginCompletedEventArgs`).

(*Note*: I am using VS 2015 and C# v6. In older versions of Visual Studio and C#, you may have to add `using System.Linq;`)

Create a generic EventArgs<T> class that inherits from EventArgs**...**

```
class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs {

  public T Value { get; private set; }

  public EventArgs(T val) {
     Value = val;
  }

}
```

Declare your event handler**...**

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs<object>> LoginCompleted;
```

Assuming you have declared and assigned an object named `loginObject`, add code to raise you event**...**

```
private void RaiseLoginCompleted() {
  if (LoginCompleted != null)
    LoginCompleted(this, new EventArgs<object>(loginObject));
}
```

In your client code, add the `LoginCompleted` event handler (uses Linq and calls a local method)**...**

```
LoginCompleted += (o, e) => onLoginCompleted(e.Value); // calls a local method

void onLoginCompleted(LoginObject obj) {
  // add your code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

sometimes it sucks to create a class for merely passing a bool as a derived `EventArgs`! so you can simply use `Action` instead of `EventHandler`. you can pass any type and how many parameters you like (Action supports Up to 16).

```
    class Raiser
    {
        public event Action<Raiser, bool,DateTimeOffset> OnCreate;

        public void Create()
        {
            OnCreate?.Invoke(this, true,DateTimeOffset.Now);
        }
    }

    class Listener
    {
        Raiser raiser;

        public Listener()
        {
            raiser = new Raiser();
            raiser.OnCreate += Raiser_OnCreate;
        }

        private void Raiser_OnCreate(Raiser arg1, bool arg2,DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();//Do Your works here
        }
    }
```

generally using `Action` and 'Func' are easier than `Delegate`.